# Using eclipse streaming audio from web url

Tags: android

I have tried to find the answer online and none are clear to me. I am starting of programming and dont know much so any assistance that makes sense would help. My brother developed a website I'm trying to stream audio from and found on the developer web page a code to use. eclipse gives me no errors but when I run the app it forces close here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  String url = "http://beatswith.us/uploads/Mac%20Miller%20-  %20Paper%20Route%20feat.%20Kev%20Da%20Hustla.mp3"; // your URL here
  MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
  mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

  try {
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
  } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  try {
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
  } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  } // might take long! (for buffering, etc)

  mediaPlayer.start();
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Its probably throwing an exception at mediaPlayer.start()

The url must be bad. looks to me like theres an actual space in your String, which is invalid. You should put setDataSource, prepare, and start in the same try/catch block

Edit:nevermind the url seems fine. Can you post the stacktrace of the exception?

Edit2: did you add your activity to the AndroidManifest.xml? Are you navigating here from another activity?

Comment: ok sorry but i have no clue what your asking for all i know is that i have no errors in my error log but log cat shows this

Comment: 01-05 23:26:10.660: I/Process(1267): Sending signal. PID: 1267 SIG: 9SurfaceViewExample
01-05 23:26:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(1267): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-05 23:26:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(1267): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=us.beats.with.Mplay }
01-05 23:26:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1409)

Comment: 01-05 23:26:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
01-05 23:26:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
01-05 23:26:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
01-05 23:26:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):  at beats.us.with.myMenu$1.onClick(myMenu.java:31)

Comment: 01-05 23:26:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
01-05 23:26:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
01-05 23:26:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-05 23:26:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-05 23:26:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)

Comment: 01-05 23:26:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-05 23:26:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-05 23:26:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)

Comment: 01-05 23:26:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-05 23:26:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-05 23:26:08.976: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Found the Answer I had my button set up with the wrong package name

Answer (score 0):

Found the Answer I had my button set up with the wrong package name